# meteor-useraccounts and alanning meteor-roles - Check role on sign-in

Tags: javascript, meteor

Is it possible to check users role on Sign in, and than if user is in role "admin" to display one page, and if is it in role "basic-user" to display another page ( go to another route).

Answer (score 4):

Lets have a look at the [Routes](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/iron-routing#routes) section of the documentation for the [useraccounts:iron-routing](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/iron-routing) package.

this should solve your problem

```
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('signIn', {
  redirect: function(){
    var user = Meteor.user();

    if (user && Roles.userIsInRole(user, ['admin'])) {
      Router.go('admin');
    }
    else {
      Router.go('home');
    }
  }
});
```

Be careful to check you can access the user `roles` field from the client side: lets check the [allanning:roles](https://atmospherejs.com/alanning/roles) official [documentation](https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles/#meteor-roles)

Answer (score 1):

To define a default role for a user I use this:

```
// server    
Accounts.onLogin(function(user) {
        var user = user.user;
        var defaultRole = ['student'];
        if (!user.roles){
            Roles.addUsersToRoles(user, defaultRole)
        };
    })
```

I'm using meteor-useraccounts and alanning meteor-roles packages and that work fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not outdated (and a look at http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_users suggests I'm not) there is no built in way for user roles. There should be some extensions for that task with which you could go and depending on what you choose you would have to check their documentation.

However it's not very hard to implement a own simple roles logic in Meteor:

First in your `Accounts.onCreateUser` function give your users object a new attribute `role` and assign them to a default role. If you don't have a `Accounts.onCreateUser` yet create one server side. It could look like something like this:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
    // Add an user roles array
    user.roles = ["default-user"];

    if (options.profile)
    user.profile = options.profile;
    return user;
}
```

Next you would need to implement some logic to add `"admin"` or whatever you like for trusted users to their roles array. That's up to you and for the beginning if you don't have dozens of admins you could also choose to do that manually in your MongoDB.

Now make sure you publish the new attribute of your user object to the currently logged in user. To do so make use of `Meteor.publish` with `null` as first parameter to address the current user like so:

```
Meteor.publish(null, function () {
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId}, {fields: {
        'roles': 1,
        'profile': 1, // You probably want to publish the profile of a user to himself
        // And here would be any other custom stuff you need
    }});
});
```

And with that you are already in a state where you can do individual styling or routing client side. For example you could do something like this:

```
if (Meteor.user().roles.indexOf("admin") > -1) {
    // Route for admins!
}
```

You could also parse through your array and add the user roles as class to your `body` element to for example only show certain elements to admins. This could be done this way:

```
Meteor.user().roles.forEach(function(role){
    $('body').addClass(role);
});
```

Note that this will only be "cosmetic" but you can also implement real security with that as long as you do it server side. So if you want a Meteoer subscription or Meteor method only to be available for admins add something like this to it:

```
var requestingUser = Meteor.users.findOne({ '_id': this.userId});
if (!_.contains(requestingUser.roles, "admin")) {
    // Terminate the pbulish function or Meteor method here when there is no "admin" role
    return;
}
```

As said, this only works sever side and should be at the start of `Meteor.publish` functions or at the start of functions within `Meteor.methods` blocks.

Comment: Thank You very much for comment. I am using alanning/meteor-roles package so I am interesed can I on loging (using useraccounts package ) check for asigned role of user and then route him to some page.